# Integrated Security MySQL/VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Why the following code:

```
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = 
    New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Integrated Security=True;")
```

Doesn't work? When I try `conn.open();` I get the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: If it cannot authenticate, there wont be a connection created.  See [Using the Windows Native Authentication Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-authentication-windows-native.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

> Use Windows authentication
>   Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;IntegratedSecurity=yes;
>   Uid=auth_windows;
>   This option is available from Connector/NET version 6.4.4The Windows Native Authentication Plugin must be installed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

i dunno if mysql accepts integrated security .

i m using this one on mysql,you give str_query it returns datatable result

```html
Public Function mysql(ByVal str_query As String) As DataTable
      Dim adptr As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim filltab As New DataTable
        Try
            Using cnn As New MySqlConnection("server=" & mysql_server & ";user=" & mysql_user & ";password=" & mysql_password & ";database=" & mysql_database & ";Allow User Variables=True")
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(str_query, cnn)
                    cnn.Open()
                                   adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    adptr.Fill(filltab)
                    cnn.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
'you can log mysql errors into a file here log(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return filltab
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it with Integrated Security.